# Creating A ER database modeling software in c#

Tags: c#, .net, model, entity-relationship

I really want to be able to create an ER software, something like the database designer for postgres sql that microolap have created. I just don't know where to start. Have tried googling for ideas but couldnt find anything. All i could see is how to create an ER model not how to do the coding behind. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't what kind of info you want, but in tech point of view I'd like to suggest you Windows Presentation Foundation because its vectorial graphics nature.

Also, I'd like to suggest you to learn an OR/M like NHibernate which has wide support to lot of database engines (SQL Server, Oracle, SQLite, Postgre...) and it'd be a valuable help for reverse-engineering existing database model, or export your E-R diagrams to relational design then to an actual database.

How to code it? Well:

1) You need graphics manipulation knowledge, because you'll have to manage the E-R entities, do the relations... So maybe, a good point would be review Paint.NET source code, and maybe you've code for reuse in your own project (http://www.afterdawn.com/software/source_codes/download_source.cfm?source_id=85)

2) You need to translate the design surface (the editor graphics) to objects, then you can use NHibernate to generate an schema based on them (check its documentation).

I hope this info was useful for you.

Comment: perfect! Just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try MySQL Workbench project for Windows (Architecture Independent).

Source Code: [MySQL Workbench Source Code for .NET](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-6.0.7-src.zip/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/)

I hope this info was useful for you.